# How can I move to ImageViews in android so that they are dependent on each other?

Tags: javascript, android, animation, animatorset

at work we have a problem regarding planing production flows and I thought about solving this with an android app.
My goal is to move two imageViews that are dependent on each other. The first step wasn't much of a problem. I moved the first ImageView from workstation one to workstation two while the second ImageView moved to workstation one. But now comes the tricky part at least for me: The ImageViews spend a certain amount of time in a work station so I want to code something like ImageView two moves only if two conditions are met: 1. If its waiting time is up and 2. the first ImageView as completed its move out of the workstation.

So here is my code so far:

```
public void startProductionCBEV(View view) {
  ImageView ftsTorsten = findViewById(R.id.fts_torsten);
  ImageView ftsTorsten1 = findViewById(R.id.fts_torsten1);

  //  Move image with objectAnimator
  ObjectAnimator animation 
  =ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ftsTorsten,"translationY", 110f);
  // animation duration
  animation.setDuration(500);

  ObjectAnimator animation1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ftsTorsten, 
  "translationX", 170f);
  animation1.setStartDelay(10000);
  animation1.setDuration(500);
...

// Making sure that each move is completed before the next one starts
  AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
  set.play(animation).before(animation1);
  set.play(animation1).before(animation2);
  set.play(animation2).before(animation3);
  set.play(animation3).before(animation4);
  ...
  set.start();


  // Making sure that each move is completed before the next one starts
  AnimatorSet set1 = new AnimatorSet();
  if(animation1.isRunning()){
      set1.play(animation100).before(animation99);
  }
  set1.play(animation99).before(animation98);
  set1.play(animation98).before(animation97);
  set1.play(animation97).before(animation96);
  set1.play(animation96).before(animation95);
  ...
  set1.start();
  }
}
```

Thanks already for anybody who is trying to help this really drives me nuts.

Comment: Have you tried `set.play(animation1).after(animation);` ??

Comment: Or start second animation once the first one is finished with OnAnimationListener

Comment: I know that I can play animation sequentially with set.play(animation1).after(animation). But that does not give me the conditions I want. Imagine the second workstation is done and therefore the second imageView moves on to the next workstation. Then imageView one should only move if its own time at its current workstation is finished otherwise it should stay there and wait.

Comment: how would you solve it with an OnAnimationListener? So far I have never used it